# Grouping together similar lines of code in the code below for some array filtering

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am repeatedly using same array filter functionality in my if else conditions however only the properties differ in each case. Is there a way to group them together or is it right the way it is below?

```
private _filter(value: string, filterIndex, type: string): string[] {
    let filterArray = [];
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    if (filterIndex == 0) {  // Index for Type
      if (type === 'Dsc') {
        this.assetTypeData.filter((option) => option.assetTypeDsc.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)).forEach(element => {
          filterArray.push(element.assetTypeDsc)
        });
      } else {
        this.assetTypeData.filter((option) => option.assetTypeCde.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)).forEach(element => {
          filterArray.push(element.assetTypeCde)
        });
      }
    } else if (filterIndex == 1) { // Index for Make

      if (type === 'Dsc') {
        this.assetMakeData.filter((option) => option.assetMakeDsc.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)).forEach(element => {
          filterArray.push(element.assetMakeDsc)
        });
      } else {
        this.assetMakeData.filter((option) => option.assetMakeCde.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)).forEach(element => {
          filterArray.push(element.assetMakeCde)
        });
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tried to group everything that could be grouped

```js
private _filter(value: string, filterIndex, type: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return (filterIndex == 0 ? this.assetTypeData : this.assetMakeData)
       .map(option => option[(filterIndex == 0 ? 'assetType': 'assetMake') + type])
       .filter(assetValue => assetValue.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the effort Andrei, actually this function might get extended with more if else conditions ahead so it might not best adapt to those changes

Comment: yet it seems "filter" logic will remain the same. at least you could group the filter logic